# Why a narrow white line appears on my UIImageView border left side?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, border

Unwanted white 1 px line appears on the left side of my UIViewImage. I'm using QuartzCore to apply border:

```
...
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];

[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor BORDERCOLOR4ALLVIEWS] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: BORDERSIZE4ALL];
...
```

The image view is inside ScrollView. I have a thumbnail image list at the bottom on the screen. When user taps a thumbnail I'm loading an image and passing it to the MyUIImageView.image. Here is the code that gets executed on tap:

```
MyUIImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
CGRect rect = MyUIImageView.frame;
rect.size.width = MyUIImageView.image.size.width; //also tried with - 1;
rect.size.height = MyUIImageView.image.size.height //also tried with - 1;

MyUIImageView.frame = rect; 

// also tried redraw a border on the image view:

[MyUIImageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor BORDERCOLOR4ALLVIEWS] CGColor]];
[MyUIImageView.layer setBorderWidth: BORDERSIZE4ALL];
```

Have noticed that line appears only on one image. However, if I'm additionally making image view frame size smaller by subtracting with -1 then white lines appear on the other images too. Here's an example of an image with a white line:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After setting MyUIImageView.clipsToBounds to YES the white line dissapeared :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess the white line is the scrollView's background color showing through. Try setting the scrollviews background color to black.

And if that doesn't help try to set the imageview's background color to clearColor.